# Embedding Images in map layouts and documents (*.mxd)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, image, mxd

I wanted to place some images in my map layout but I found that images are not embedded in the MXD files so now, after I deleted them, I've lost the graphics and have to do them again.

Is here any way to embed the image in the MXD files itself? If not, where would you suggest I place the images; the geodatabase that comes with the map(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you open up the Properties dialog for the picture element, you can state that you want it to be saved with the MXD:

[image: Picture Properties]